# Kalman filter with different sampling rate

Tags: sensors, prediction, kalman-filter, sensor-fusion

I cant seem to find a thread about this specific issue so therefore I post one myself.

I am working on a large navigation project where I have access to the odometry of the veghicle and a position estimate derived from LiDAR data. I can vary the sample from the LiDAR estimation from 1-20 Hz with varying quality and the odometry data is trasmitted at 40Hz.

I have implemented a standard kalman filter, following these equations (from Wikipedia):

**Prediction**

[image]

[image]

**Update**

[image]

My question is now, how do you (optimally) use a Kalman filter when the sampling rate from the different information sources are different?

Comment: There's no requirement for a fixed time step with a Kalman filter, so you can vary the time-step used in Prediction to get to the time of the next measurement, then perform an Update.  The matrices F and Q do change with the time-step size, so they need to be recomputed on the fly.

Comment: @KeithBrodie Thank you for the answer, but are you sure? Because I came across some articles mentioning that when the sampling interval differ then you either need to lower one of the sampling rates or interpolate the other one.

Comment: I think you mean the situation, in which you observe only a subset of your measurements. In this case you need to use a sequential Kalman Filter, so you can proceed update only using the part of the measurement vector.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches:

*First, lets assume an "iteration" is a kalman filter predict + update*

1. **Variable dt**: If you can measure your delta time between kalman filter iterations, you can basically run a new iteration every time a new measurement arrives from any sensor.
2. **Static dt**: If your delta time must remain static, you can only run iterations at a fixed rate. Thus, you must store sensor measurements that arrive between each iteration run.

Now there is a general question around if you can break the measurements down into different "sub-updates", meaning that you run a single predict, and for each sensor measurement that comes in, you do a separate update step. This would notionally allow you to perform updates for only sensors that have provided new data (which applies to both cases above).  It would look something like this:

1. predict()
2. update() with sensor A
3. *skip update() for sensor B since no measurement arrived*
4. update() with sensor c
5. repeat

Theoretically speaking, you shouldn't this for the following reasons:

1. By not predicting before each update, you run the risk of your system's real-world dynamics outpacing the filter. The update() method compares a real world measurement against a predicted measurement that is specifically calculated from the predicted state. If enough time passes between predict() and update(), update() will essentially compare new measurements against old predictions. If your filter runs much faster than your system's states can change in the real world, then you are fine. But if your filter runs relatively slow compared to state changes in the real system, you will experience lag/inaccuracy in the filter's estimation of the state.
2. Performing a separate update for each measurement will result in lots of unnecessarily redundant mathematical matrix operations (which can be very costly if F is large). Assuming your F and H have non-diagonal components (and thus states/observations are interrelated), then do a single predict and a single update with all recent measurements to minimize costly matrix calculations. If F is purely diagonal, or segments of it are purely diagonal, then you have certain states or groups of states that are completely independent of one another. To save on matrix computation, you should split these into different kalman filters.

Others have suggested that, to avoid problem 2 above, you split your H matrix (and thus associated y, z, S, K) into separate, smaller matrices for each sensor. So sensor A would have it's own H,y,z,S,K matrices, sensor B it's own set of matrices, etc. **If you have non-diagonal elements in F or H, this is not optimal.** Non-diagonal elements imply a state's dependence on another state, so they will exhibit covariance. K is ultimately calculated based on the predicted state covariance as well as the predicted observation covariance (also keep in mind if you have state covariance, it typically injects covariance into the predicted observations through H, not to mention H may create additional covariance on it's own). If you start segmenting out a system-wide H,S matrix into separate H,S matrices for each sensor, you wind up cutting out the relationships between your model's interrelated states/observations. This results in a sub-optimal K because certain covariances are removed.